# Input-view selection-of not working correctly

Tags: bixby

I am trying to display a list of profiles for the user and have the hands-free navigation enabled. Whenever I use selection-of in render, the view does not get rendered correctly.

I have tried putting the layout into a layout-macro before, but I get the same result, so I would prefer to have the view in just one file.

```
input-view {
  match: Profile (profile) {
      from-output: GetProfiles
  }
  message {
    template ("These are the list of profiles under your account.")
  }
  render {
    if (size(profile) > 1) {
      selection-of (profile) {
        navigation-mode {
          read-many {
            page-size (size(profile))
            list-summary ("There are #{size(profile)} profiles.")
            page-content{
              underflow-statement (These are the first set)
              page-selection-question (Do you want to select one of these?)
              item-selection-question (Which one would you like?)
              overflow-statement (That's all I have)
              overflow-question (What would you like to do?)
            }
          }
        }
        where-each (item) {
          title-card {
            title-area {
              halign (Start)
              slot1 {
                single-line {
                  text {
                    style (Detail_L_Soft)
                    value ("Account: #{value(item.acctName)}")
                  }
                }
              }
              slot2 {
                single-line {
                  text {
                    style (Detail_M_Soft)
                    value ("Web property: #{value(item.webName)}")
                  }
                }
              }
              slot3 {
                single-line {
                  text {
                    style (Title_S)
                    value ("Profile: #{value(item.viewName)}")
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The message and layout seem to not get used, but instead displays the list like this:

```
Here are sixteen profiles.
2.0.3-teamname.capsule.Profile
2.0.3-teamname.capsule.Profile
2.0.3-teamname.capsule.Profile
2.0.3-teamname.capsule.Profile
2.0.3-teamname.capsule.Profile
2.0.3-teamname.capsule.Profile
2.0.3-teamname.capsule.Profile
2.0.3-teamname.capsule.Profile
2.0.3-teamname.capsule.Profile
2.0.3-teamname.capsule.Profile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this input view is the one matching the moment?

> Here are sixteen profiles.

... makes it sound like you're on a *result* moment.

Try converting this to a `result-view`.

Comment: You are right. Now I have to figure out how it can be an input-view so then I can pass the value the user selects into another action.

Answer (score 1):

`GetProfiles` sounds like it retrieves a bunch of Profiles which makes it a `result-view`. If the intent is to select from the output of this function, this function should feed into a `computed-input` that is part of an `Action`.

Comment: So it seems that yes, when converted to result-view, it appears as it should, but the "read-many" does not read out loud the results. Could you also elaborate on how computed-input works? I am trying to have the user select a profile, hands-free, from the output of the function, which then will call an action to get information about that profile.

Comment: KPta, great questions. Please ask them in a new question as needed for better visibility.